# How to sort array of objects with boolean values: true, false and null

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hi i have an array of objects that i want to sort based on a boolean that one of the objects has. However normally there would be either `true` or `false` but in this case we also check on `null` values because sometimes the data has not been set and in that case we wanna show that it has yet to be set with an icon.

Here's an example of the array:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    id: 69,
    boolean: true,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 42,
    boolean: false,
    name: 'bar',
  },
  {
    id: 666,
    boolean: null,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 420,
    boolean: false,
    name: 'bar',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    boolean: null,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    boolean: true,
    name: 'foo',
  },
]
```

So what i tried first was:

```js
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => b.boolean - a.boolean);
```

This sets the objects that are `true` at the front but the objects with `false` or `null` are scattered.

Then i tried:

```js
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b, c) => (c.boolean - b.boolean) - a.boolean);
```

This just didn't work at all.

I couldn't really find a case that was similar enough to base a solution off of it so hopefully i can find it here.

Comment: What order do you want them in?

Comment: btw, the callback for `sort` takes only two parameters.

Comment: @evolutionxbox true > null > false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to use a custom sorting, you could take an object with the wanted sorting, like

```js
const
    order = { true: 1, null: 2, false: 3 };
    data = [{ id: 69, boolean: true, name: 'foo' }, { id: 42, boolean: false, name: 'bar' }, { id: 666, boolean: null, name: 'foo' }, { id: 420, boolean: false, name: 'bar' }, { id: 2, boolean: null, name: 'foo' }, { id: 123, boolean: true, name: 'foo' }];

data.sort((a, b) => order[a.boolean] - order[b.boolean]);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have unknown values and want to move them to bottom, you could add another key with a large value, like

```
order = { true: 1, null: 2, false: 3, bottom: Number.MAX_VALUE };
```

Usage:

```
data.sort((a, b) =>
    (order[a.boolean] || order.bottom) - (order[b.boolean] || order.bottom)
);
```

Comment: I thought the sort return should be `-1, 0, 1`? - `{ true: -1, null: 0, false: 1 }`

Comment: @evolutionxbox, right, this is working as well, but it prevents using a default value, if you like to move unknown values to top, bottom, or inbetween.

Comment: is `order` in this case the object where the wanted order is saved in? So
`const order = { true: 1, null: 2, false: 3 }`

Comment: @MarnixElling, it is. please see edit.

Comment: I'm assuming this works if the array had just booleans in it but its an array of objects where 1 of the property of each object is a boolean, i tried to expand `order[a] - order[b]` into `order[a.boolean] - order[b.boolean]` but that isn't working, what am i missing?

Comment: @MarnixElling, please add a small set of data.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've editted the post with an example

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the `null` explicitly ...

```js
let list = [{i: 0, boolean: true}, { i: 1, boolean: null}, { i:2, boolean: false}, { i: 4, boolean: true}]

function cpBoolWithNull(a,b) {
  //if both are null return 0 to maintain a stable sort
  //if only one is null return 0 or 1 depending on the value of the other
  if (a.boolean === null) return b.boolean === null ? 0 : b.boolean ? 1 : -1;
  if (b.boolean === null) return a.boolean ? -1 : 1;

  //if both are different from null, sort true before false
  return b.boolean - a.boolean
}

console.log(list.sort(cpBoolWithNull));
```

This will sort  `true`  ... `null`  ... `false`  If you need a differnt order, adjust the return values.

Answer (score -4):

I think that you can have a type checker with JS with this simple script.

```js
let array =[true, false, null];
function check(i){
if (array[i] != null||array[i]!=false){ 

 if (array[i]!=null || array[i]!=true)document.write(" Array item"+" "+i+" "+"has the value of boolean false. ");

 if (array[i]!=true||array[i]!=false)document.write(" Array item"+" "+i+" "+"has the value of boolean true. ");

if (array[i] != true || array[i] != false  )document.write(" Array item"+" "+i+" "+"has the value of object null. ");
document.write("<br>")
}
}
check(0);
```

You can comment out the other text when it is not needed.

Comment: The question is actually asking ways to sort array of object with boolean property rather than to sort boolean array. You could check the question again and improve your answer.